# Resolving keybinding conflicts with Evil-mode: Troubleshooting Image-Dired bindings

Tags: key-bindings, evil, images, image-dired

I am trying to move/rename 100+ images inside of a directory, so I am using Image-Dired to view the images as thumbnails and as I move/rename them.

I want to move multiple images at a time, so I am "marking" the thumbnailed images with `image-dired-mark-thumb-original-file`, which marks the associated file in the dired buffer. After this, I can move all of the marked files as usual using dired.

Since I am using Evil-mode, the default keybindings do not work in the image-dired thumbnail buffer, so I am planning to map some basic keybindings, such as `l` and `h` to move forward/backward one image, and `m` and `u` to mark/unmark the image files in the dired buffer.

I tried the following, but the keybindings are still being shadowed by evil-mode:

```
(defun image-dired-keybindings()
  (message "making keybindings!")
  (local-unset-key (kbd "l"))
  (local-unset-key (kbd "h"))
  (local-unset-key (kbd "m"))
  (local-unset-key (kbd "u"))
  (local-set-key (kbd "m") 
                 'image-dired-mark-thumb-original-file)
  (local-set-key (kbd "u") 
                 'image-dired-unmark-thumb-original-file)
  (local-set-key (kbd "l") 
                 'image-dired-forward-image)
  (local-set-key (kbd "h") 
                 'image-dired-backward-image)
  (message "making keybindings finished"))


(add-hook 'image-dired-thumbnail-mode-hook
          'image-dired-keybindings)
```

Any suggestions? My `*Messages*` buffer is logging the debug messages, and here is some detail on the modes in my image dired thumbnail buffer:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor Column-Number Desktop-Save Electric-Indent Erc-Autojoin
Erc-Button Erc-Fill Erc-Irccontrols Erc-List Erc-Match Erc-Menu
Erc-Move-To-Prompt Erc-Netsplit Erc-Networks Erc-Noncommands
Erc-Pcomplete Erc-Readonly Erc-Ring Erc-Stamp Erc-Track Evil
Evil-Local File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Auto-Complete
Global-Font-Lock Global-Hl-Line Global-Undo-Tree Global-Visual-Line
Imagex-Global-Sticky Imagex-Sticky Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel
Read-Only Show-Paren Size-Indication Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree
Yas Yas-Global

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

image-dired-thumbnail mode defined in `image-dired.el':
Browse and manipulate thumbnail images using dired.
Use `image-dired-dired' and `image-dired-setup-dired-keybindings' to get a
nice setup to start with.

This mode runs the hook `image-dired-thumbnail-mode-hook', as the final step
during initialization.

key             binding
---             -------

C-b             image-dired-backward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
C-d             image-dired-delete-char
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
C-f             image-dired-forward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
RET             image-dired-display-thumbnail-original-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
C-n             image-dired-next-line
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
C-p             image-dired-previous-line
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
SPC             image-dired-display-next-thumbnail-original
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
.               image-dired-track-original-file
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
D               image-dired-thumbnail-set-image-description
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
L               image-dired-rotate-original-left
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
R               image-dired-rotate-original-right
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
c               image-dired-comment-thumbnail
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
d               image-dired-flag-thumb-original-file
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
g               Prefix Command
h               image-dired-backward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
l               image-dired-forward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
m               image-dired-mark-thumb-original-file
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
q               image-dired-kill-buffer-and-window
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
r               image-dired-rotate-thumbnail-right
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
t               Prefix Command
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
u               image-dired-unmark-thumb-original-file
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
DEL             image-dired-display-previous-thumbnail-original
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
<C-mouse-1>     image-dired-mouse-toggle-mark
<C-return>      image-dired-thumbnail-display-external
<delete>        image-dired-flag-thumb-original-file
<down>          image-dired-next-line
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
<left>          image-dired-backward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
<mouse-1>       image-dired-mouse-select-thumbnail
<mouse-2>       image-dired-mouse-display-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
<right>         image-dired-forward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
<tab>           image-dired-jump-original-dired-buffer
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
<up>            image-dired-previous-line
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)

g f             image-dired-line-up
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
g g             image-dired-line-up-dynamic
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
g i             image-dired-line-up-interactive
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)

...TRUNCATED FOR BREVITY....
```

And inside the image-dired-thumbnail buffer, running `C-h k` for the command `l` shows that `l` is still bound to the evil-mode keybinding `evil-forward-char`:

```
l runs the command evil-forward-char, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in `evil-commands.el'.

It is bound to <right>, SPC, l.

(evil-forward-char &optional COUNT CROSSLINES NOERROR)

Move cursor to the right by COUNT characters.
Movement is restricted to the current line unless CROSSLINES is non-nil.
If NOERROR is non-nil, don't signal an error upon reaching the end
of the line or the buffer; just return nil.
```

How to I resolve this conflict to easily mark and traverse images in my images-dired-thumbnail buffer?

---

**Update**

Following @Drew's suggestion below, I tried resolving this using the `image-dired-thumbnail-mode-map`, as shown below:

```
(add-hook 'image-dired-thumbnail-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
            (define-key image-dired-thumbnail-mode-map "l" 'image-dired-forward-image)
            (define-key image-dired-thumbnail-mode-map "h" 'image-dired-backward-image)
            (define-key image-dired-thumbnail-mode-map "u" 'image-dired-unmark-thumb-original-file)
            (define-key image-dired-thumbnail-mode-map "m" 'image-dired-mark-thumb-original-file)
            )
          )
```

I also tried substituting `"l"` with `(kbd "l")`, but no success. I am still getting the same issue, where my mode help menu lists the key bindings as `currently shadowed by another mode`. `C-h m` shows the same conflicts:

```
h               image-dired-backward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
l               image-dired-forward-image
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
```

Any suggestions?

Also, I double-checked my version of `image-dired` using `list-packages`, and it was listed as 0.4.11. I believe the source is [here](http://web.mit.edu/Emacs/source/emacs/lisp/image-dired.el)

Comment: I don't really follow all that you are saying. But if you use `local-set-key` then you must be in a buffer with the proper mode (the mode you want). If I had to guess, I'd guess that you are not in the buffer/mode that you want to be. Why not just use `define-key` with the proper keymap? E.g., if you want to bind a key in `image-dired-thumbnail-mode` then use keymap `image-dired-thumbnail-mode-map`. (Dunno whether those are the mode & map you want, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the tip, it was very helpful. I made an attempt at your suggestion, and updated my question because I am still getting the same error using `define-key`. I also updated the wording of my question; hopefully that is more clear. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there was some kind of evil-mode conflict. The following line fixed everything:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'image-dired-thumbnail-mode 'emacs)
```

I hope this helps someone :-)

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answer. That lets someone who has the same question know what the answer is. And it prevents someone looking for unanswered questions from stumbling on this one.